# Homework: Iterator method which uses private iterator class

Tags: java, inheritance, iterator

I have a homework assignment and there's one thing I can't get hold of.

I have an abstract class, which contains methods. I must create a subclass that inherits and extends those methods. And there's one method in that abstract class which I don't understand. Does anybody know what this piece of code does?

All other methods in this class do different things with arrays (like add or remove specific integer). Some other methods create a LiFo stack (push, pop, peek, I hope you know what I mean). But I have no problems with other methods it's just this one I don't understand:

```
/*This is a method which I can use in my subclass and main method: */
public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
    return new IntIterator();
}


/*This is a private inner class used by iterator() */
class IntIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {
    private int count = 0;
    public Integer next() {return values[count++];}

    public boolean hasNext() {return count<size;}

    public void remove() {
        throw new RuntimeException("remove() is not implemented");
    }
}
```

"Size" variale represents actual array or stack size, "values" is an array which stores all integers.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't understand the `iterator()` method? What about it don't you understand?

Comment: What don't you understand about the code you posted? The private inner class seems relatively straightforward. What about it confuses you?

Comment: It's nice to see a "homework" question that is polite and well written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is creating s simple iterator to iterate over an array called `values`. An iterator just lets you use a collection a little easier. Instead of this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.size; i++)
{
    System.out.println(values[i]);
}
```

you do this:

```
Iterator i = iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    System.out.printf(i.next());
}
```

This doesn't seem like a big win here but it can be when the underlying collection type is more complex than an array.

Answer (score 0):

The *purpose* of the `iterator` method is probably to provide the stuff necessary for use with the `for` statement.  If you say something like

```
for (SomeType val : SomeObject)
```

then if `SomeObject` isn't an array, it must be something that implements `Iterable<SomeType>` [technically, it could implement just `Iterable` or `Iterable<T>` for some subclass of `SomeType`].  If a class implements `Iterable<SomeType>`, it must have an `iterator` method:

```
public Iterator<SomeType> iterator() { ... }
```

When the above `for` statement is executed, it starts by creating an `Iterator<SomeType>`:

```
internalIterator = SomeObject.iterator();
```

The `for` statement then calls the `next` and `hasNext` methods on the `internalIterator` to examine each object in turn, and to know when to stop the loop.  Thus, the `Iterator<SomeType>` has a `next` method that will return the "next" value each time it's called.  In effect, calling `next` multiple times returns a *list* of values, one at a time. In this case, the `Iterator<Integer>` holds onto a `count` index that tells it what value to return next, and its `next()` method returns the next value.